# Using cURL to get script content

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm using cURL to access a site. The problem is that content that I need to grab is generated by a script as:

```
function Button(){
...
document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = name;
}

<p id="out"></p>
```

With cURL, I have the code of the page but not the content.
I'm using this config:

```
  $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
$redirects=5000;
$data = curl_redirect_exec($curl,$redirects);
curl_close($curl);
```

I could get the content generate by the script.

Comment: read this http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get data rendered in JS from PHP CURL. What you need is a headless browser, something that runs client side scripts like [Phantom.JS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Casper.JS](http://casperjs.org/) which have the capability of running Client-Side JavaScript.